# Using BindIPEndPointDelegate to specify the source port doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, servicepoint, servicepointmanager

I've searched all over on how to use BindIPEndPointDelegate to change the source port of my HttpWebRequest.  I have found multiple posts on this:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451559/how-to-properly-use-bindipendpointdelegate) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451559/how-to-properly-use-bindipendpointdelegate/11900706#11900706)

However, It doesn't seem to be working for me.   I found the same issue with this guy:
[Define Outgoing/Calling Port for SOAP Web Service in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055386/define-outgoing-calling-port-for-soap-web-service-in-visual-studio-2010/13056014#13056014)

Basically, I want to change my source port when connecting to a webpage.  BindIPEndPointDelegate is pretty straigh forward.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEp, retryCount) =>
             {
                 return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8086);
             };
```

When I look at the connections with netstat -n, I expect to see  myipaddress:8086  as the source and the destination IP:80.  What I see in netstat is that it is creating a loopback (127.0.0.1:8086) with my specified port.  See screen shot of [netstat -n](http://www.ecrm-online.com/dl/netstat.jpg)

Since this is my first post, I can't post images.  So the image can be found [here](http://www.ecrm-online.com/dl/netstat.jpg)

Why does BindIPEndPointDelegate create a loop back connection and how can I get my WebRequest to behave like the browser with my specified port?

I'm on a win7 Pro box, No local firewall, Not going through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today.  I selected a particular source port in the BindIPEndPointDelegate, but with WireShark I always saw a different source port than what I selected.  Then I discovered that I was implicitly using a Proxy by using the [Fiddler2 Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Once I turned off Fiddler, then I started seeing the source port numbers in WireShark that I requested in the Bind delegate.

The upshot is that if you have a proxy anywhere you might see this same behavior.